# Bibliographic References on Denoising Distributed Acoustic data with Deep Learning

Tags: denoising, reference-request, deep-learning

**Distributed Acoustic Sensing (DAS)**

I have an iDAS (intelligent distributed acoustic sensing) dataset obtain from an undersea optical fibre. iDAS data have a 2D dimensional representation. On the one axis we have the channel axis, i.e. the point on the cable from which we measure the strain rate obtained from the backscatter light (Rayleigh Backscatter) on that point and on the other axis we have the sampling points obtained with fixed frequency in time. Therefore, iDAS data have both spatial and temporal information. Another way to think of this is by looking a particular channel, then, for this fixed channel we obtain a signal which measures the strain rate of the cable with respect to time.

**Motivation**

This technology can be used in various applications, e.g. earthquake detection (see [[1](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-15824-6)] and this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2XyMu_3fqY) fro example), for detecting volcanic events [[3](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-29184-w)] and many others. However, a big challenge on these datasets is to alleviate the noise that might occur from irrelevant events. My aim is approach this problem via a Self-Supervised Deep learning approach. There are a some papers in the literature addressing this approach such as [[4](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a7e6/1d3c1f69412a26bb1e6f29518ecec72daef3.pdf)]. I have verified the approach in [[4](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a7e6/1d3c1f69412a26bb1e6f29518ecec72daef3.pdf)] on the datasets that the authors use and works also in some other cases. However, I would like to improve the results on a specific dataset.

**Question**

Therefore, I would be very pleased if anyone can provide any references, ideas or approaches (e.g. different architectures) for this problem. One idea is to approach to this problem via Vision Transformers, e.g. similar to [[5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.06377.pdf)]. Also, papers related to signal denoising via Self Supervised techniques might also provide valuable information related to the problem.

**References**

[[1](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-020-15824-6)] *Distributed acoustic sensing of microseismic sources and wave propagation in glaciated terrain.*

[[2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q2XyMu_3fqY)] *Fiber Optic Seismology In Theory And Practice (Video Webinar on YouTube).*

[[3](https://www.nature.com/articles/s41467-022-29184-w)] *Fibre optic distributed acoustic sensing of volcanic events.*

[[4](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/a7e6/1d3c1f69412a26bb1e6f29518ecec72daef3.pdf)] *A Self-Supervised Deep Learning Approach for
Blind Denoising and Waveform Coherence
Enhancement in Distributed Acoustic Sensing Data.*

[[5](https://arxiv.org/pdf/2111.06377.pdf)] *Masked Autoencoders Are Scalable Vision Learners.*

Comment: that's a cool setup, underwater virbration measurement through optical fibres.

Comment: You could understand your problem to be similar to the equalization problem for communications. Are you familiar with equalizers?

Comment: @MarcusMüller No unfortunately am not. Although a good source to the problem would nice if you want to share and think its going to help or at least provide some better intuition.

Comment: Nice question! Welcome to SE.SP.

Answer (score 5):

I'll compare this to the problem of equalization in optical fibres.

Assume a single straight fibre for a start, and neglect noise.

There's some localized phenomenon that effects a pressure wave to propagate through the water in which that fibre is suspended, straining it in different positions. Probably, this is overlayed with some slower, less localized effects (basically, plane wavefronts hitting the fibre at different angles.

The  strain over fibre distance is hence a function of the geometric distance of source of phenomenon, potentially different propagation speeds (if we need to assume the water isn't homogenous w.r.t. that), yielding a different delay between source and strain effect, and the excitation of that source; that means we can model the source –> strain-over-length channel as one linear channel with an array of 1D *impulse responses* (or, if we want to stay spatially continuous, a 2D impulse response).

There's different ways of evaluating the Rayleigh scattering, but we can basically all break them down to sending in a pulse (or a spread pulse) and looking for the echos (or, if necessary, despread at the receiver to get a pulse + echos).

So, we can also model this, for any fixed instant, as an (1D) impulse response. The impulse response depends on the strain-over-length; it's basically equivalent. It's a time-dependent function of the strain as described above.

In total we get:

1. Source signal —>
2. Convolution with 2D impulse response (location relative to source × time) —>
3. Convolution with 2D impulse response (length along cable × time) —>
4. observed signal

Therein, 2. and 3. are  linear operators of concatenable dimensionality, which we can't really tell apart – so, we'll treat that *one* unknown linear mapping.

(That's, by the way, the polystatic radar problem.)

Sadly, neither do you know 1., nor is 4. free of noise. This is a bit of an *equalizer* problem: The *one* job of communications technology is to establish knowledge of what some source sent at a receiver, under noise, and under an unknown channel. An equalizer's job is to "revert" the channel as good as possible without making noise worse more than you learn about the original signal through that, to get the channel out of the equation.

In wireless/wired/optical comms, you can often exploit knowledge on the signal (1.) in your equalizer: usually, you build both sides of a communication system, so that you can make the transmitter transmit some wideband fixed sequence whose (conjugate) time-inverse you can directly use to convolve the received signal, finding an approximation of the impulse response of the channel. Or, you make use of statistical properties ("every fixed time interval a complex value of of magnitude 1 is sent", "if I look every fixed time interval $T$, the values are uncorrelated" etc). If you can't know such things about the transmit signal, it's called a *blind* equalizer (or more generally, a blind estimator).

If you could find an equalizer that combines knowledge from all your fibers, which would allow you to reconstruct the whole-system impulse response, you'd have built something that you can use to identify, for each fiber, which part of the observation is caused by the phenomenon you're interested in, and which is uncorrelated noise.

Now, small problem: I'd assume you have very limited data where you know exactly what part of that (probably pretty large, pretty noisy) set of distance-strain observations is the noise and what the effect of the phenomenon.

I'd argue this might be a good time for a GAN, a Generative Adversarial Network.

I'll assume you have a basic simulator for the source phenomenon -> strain distribution system.

Think of it as first building a discriminator between "real observation" and "simulated observation that's not real". Think of the discriminator as a black box with a switch between two inputs, either "simulated clean data" or "preprocessed real noisy input". You don't tell it which input is active, the job of the discriminator is to tell you which.
Now, I wrote "preprocessed": the preprocessor's job is to *fool* the discriminator into thinking it's dealing with real, no-noise input data. The idea in the end is that this "fooling" so-called *generator* learns to, by trying to trick the generator into thinking it's producing clean data, denoise/de-distort the observation.

Herein lies the trick: you alternate between training the discriminator and the generator. In the end, you've got a Generator that you can use as preprocessor to remove much noise.

> Lauinger, Vincent, et al. "Blind and Channel-agnostic Equalization Using Adversarial Networks." arXiv preprint [arXiv:2209.07277](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.07277) (2022)

does exactly that to solve the equalization problem in nonlinear fiber optical channels. Here, the generator takes over the role of an equalizer. You would not necessarily learn an equalizer as well, but your problem reminded me enough of this problem that I wanted to draw the parallels, so that you can more easily understand the paper.

The nice thing is: you can define the boundaries of what your generator should learn to your own likings. Maybe reproducing plausible strain-over-distance vectors for a bunch of fibers is the thing you need? Fine! Maybe you want to actually do source location, so the output is actually a source-location-over-time estimate vector? Fine!

Comment: Disclaimer: Lauinger and Schmalen are my colleague and boss, respectively, I'm working on different things than this, but I'm certainly not unbiased ;) Also, you might want to look into earlier publications of Lauinger about using variational autoencoders to tackle the equalization problem.

Comment: @Thanks for your comprehensive response. I'll have to check the paper you've quoted to gain a better understanding of your correspondence to the equalization and see if I can do something similar. I'll come back again.

Comment: @ChrisNick92 you're more than welcome. Giving you something to read and a bit of the motivation from the field you're not familiar to was the whole idea.